# Proof that a compact surface has a tangent plane orthogonal to position

Tags: differential-topology, vector-analysis, compact-manifolds

> Given a compact surface $S$, is it true that $S$ has a tangent plane that is orthogonal to the position vector for at least one of its points?

I believe that the statement is true, but I'm having trouble writing a formal proof. My idea is that, evaluating the position and tangent vectors at a starting point and moving it along the surface until we get back to the start, the dot product must be zero somewhere. I don't know if this is completely right or even how to write this down properly, would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Suppose that the origin $O \notin S$ and consider the map defined on $S$ by $\Vert x \Vert^2$. What happens for a point $a$ such that $f$ is minimum at $a$?

Comment: I see, this is actually pretty nice. The point that minimizes the distance from the origin to the surface is guaranteed to be orthogonal to the surface's tangent at that point. There might be other points where the position is orthogonal to the tangent, but this guarantees that there will be at least one.

Also, I imagine that when $O \in S$ it's easy to show that the position is orthogonal to the tangent at the origin.